# How do I access list values in a dictionary based on key matches in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
{'A': [5.0, 6.20], 'B': [1.92, 3.35], 'C': [3.21, 7.0], 'D': [2.18, 9.90]}
```

I will then manipulate the numbers according to the key matches.

So for example, `A`, I'd take those numbers and plug-into an equation accordingly.

```
x/100 * y/100 = 5.0/100 * 6.20/100
```

Note that this is part of a function that returns values.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `dict comprehension` to do this for each key.

```
{k:(x/100) * (y/100) for k,(x,y) in d.items()}
```

```
{'A': 0.0031000000000000003,
 'B': 0.0006432,
 'C': 0.002247,
 'D': 0.0021582000000000003}
```

Accessing a single key's value in a dictionary is as simple as just `d['A']` or `d.get('A')`

Read more about dict comprehensions [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary-comprehension/).

**EDIT:** Thanks for the cleaner code suggestion @Olvin Roght

Comment: or `x*y/10000`....

Answer (score 0):

After accessing the dictionary values with their key, in this example `'A'` then access the list values with their index. Index `[0]` of the list holds `'val1'` for example. Which you can then assign to a variable and do your math.

[dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)

**Code**

---

```py
dic = {'A':['val1', 'val2']}

x = dic['A'][0]
y = dic['A'][1]

print(x, y)
```

**Result**

---

```
val1 val2
```